# Как сделать удобное подключение бота

Tags: python, exe, бот, msi

Я написал бота на питоне для ВК и телеграмм. Мне нужно будет передать этого бота другим людям, не знающим питона, чтобы они его запустили его либо у себя на компьютере, либо на сервере. Нужно как то дать возможность вводить токен и id группы или логин и пароль, в общем как это сделать, чтобы пользователю не нужно было менять значение в коде, как например exe, запустил и он работает,только нужно как то передать туда аргументы в виде того же логина с паролем или id с токеном

Comment: Текстовые файлы норм

Comment: @eri нет, мне желательно не демонстрировать и не давать распространять код пользователю

Comment: Текстовый файл я имею ввиду отдельный файл

Answer (score 0):

Одно из костыльных, но всё-таки допустимых решений в мелких проектах - хранение данных в открытом виде в конфиг-файле:

```
CONFIG_PATH = "C:\\bot_folder\\" # Путь к файлу. В идеале - абсолютный
CONFIG_NAME = "bot.cfg" # название конфиг-файла

# Пробуем открыть файл конфига
try:
  f = open(CONFIG_PATH + CONFIG_NAME, 'r')
  f.close()
# Если его нет - спрашиваем у пользователя данные и записываем их в конфиг
except FileNotFoundError:
  token = input("Введите токен > ")
  login = input("Введите логин > ")
  passw = input("Введите пароль > ")

  f = open(CONFIG_PATH + CONFIG_NAME, 'w')
  f.write(token + '\n' + login + '\n' + passw)
  f.close()

# Теперь данные в конфиге точно есть - читаем их.
with open(CONFIG_PATH + CONFIG_NAME, 'r') as config:
  config_data = config.readlines()
  token = config_data[0].strip('\n')
  login = config_data[1].strip('\n')
  passw = config_data[2].strip('\n')

  # Данные готовы к использования. Для примера выведем их
  print(token, login, passw, sep = ' | ')

  # Дальнейшая работа с данными располагается тут
```

Для более безопасного хранения данных следует прибегнуть к их шифрованию

Comment: Спасибо, воспользуюсь

Comment: @Руслан если ответ решает ваш вопрос, вы можете поставить возле него галочку, чтобы отметить как правильный

Comment: хочу посмотреть, какие ещё есть предложения